# App crashing only on Device

Tags: swift, null, crash, device

This strange crash happens only running on Devices, while in simulator works normally.
Debugging line by line, i noticed that it occurs while i append a String Value to an Array of Doubles. To do that i convert the double using an extension:

```
extension String {
func toDouble() -> Double? {
    return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(self)?.doubleValue
    }
}
```

So the crashing line is:

```
litros.append(temp_litros.toDouble()!) //litros is my array and temp_litros my string
```

the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I really don't understand why it works in simulator and it doesn't on devices.

Anyone have an ideia what could be happening here? Thanks in advance!

Crash Report:

```
Incident Identifier: 49F378A2-E7D9-4985-B208-99F529AE8813
CrashReporter Key:   fe58b29412047d4d8980b9cb66ae017f1c2db7d5
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             Nuvem [9479]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8989627A-4064-428C-888B-C09F00A3EA0B/Nuvem.app/Nuvem
Identifier:          br.com.gimenez.Nuvem
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-07-23 18:07:12.529 -0300
Launch Time:         2015-07-23 18:07:05.037 -0300
OS Version:          iOS 8.4 (12H143)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100659474
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100659474 0x100598000 + 791668
1   Nuvem                           0x00000001000b5110 Nuvem.GraficoViewController.viewDidLoad (Nuvem.GraficoViewController)() -> () (GraficoViewController.swift:69)
2   Nuvem                           0x00000001000b5410 @objc Nuvem.GraficoViewController.viewDidLoad (Nuvem.GraficoViewController)() -> () (GraficoViewController.swift:0)
3   UIKit                           0x0000000188d14c14 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 688
4   UIKit                           0x0000000188d14924 -[UIViewController view] + 28
5   UIKit                           0x0000000188eb71ec -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 708
6   UIKit                           0x0000000188dc9e80 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 464
7   UIKit                           0x0000000188dc9c4c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 52
8   UIKit                           0x0000000188dc9bcc -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 196
9   UIKit                           0x0000000188d116f0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 576
10  QuartzCore                      0x000000018864ddb4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
11  QuartzCore                      0x000000018864881c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 316
12  QuartzCore                      0x00000001886486c0 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 28
13  QuartzCore                      0x0000000188647e54 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 272
14  QuartzCore                      0x0000000188647bd4 CA::Transaction::commit() + 524
15  QuartzCore                      0x00000001886412fc CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 76
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001842542a0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018425122c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 356
18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018425160c __CFRunLoopRun + 832
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018417d2d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
20  GraphicsServices                0x000000018dbd36f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
21  UIKit                           0x0000000188d7af3c UIApplicationMain + 1484
22  Nuvem                           0x00000001000ad9b8 main (AppDelegate.swift:14)
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000196612a04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196710c24 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001965f5e6c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001965e7998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019672bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c52d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019672bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c52d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019672bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c52d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019672bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c52d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196710e0c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196710c84 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184253720 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184251674 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018417d2d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183c5a590 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 436
6   Foundation                      0x000000018519ddb4 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c7dc4 _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c7d20 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c4ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019672b498 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184259124 __CFSocketManager + 668
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c7dc4 _pthread_body + 160
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c7d20 _pthread_start + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c4ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019672bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c52d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019672bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c52d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019672bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c52d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019672bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c52d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c4eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196710e0c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000196710c84 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184253720 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184251674 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018417d2d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   Foundation                      0x00000001850b54c4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 312
6   Foundation                      0x000000018510f80c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92
7   Nuvem                           0x00000001000e64f8 +[PBAFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (PBAFURLConnectionOperation.m:151)
8   Foundation                      0x000000018519ddb4 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c7dc4 _pthread_body + 160
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c7d20 _pthread_start + 156
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001967c4ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000100588b80   x1: 0x00000001742f6a00   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x0000000196765a74
    x4: 0x000000016fd80e38   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x00000001742f6b80   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000100584800  x11: 0x00000000005d0bda
   x12: 0x00000000fffffff2  x13: 0x00000001887c5480  x14: 0x0000000000000053  x15: 0x000000000000004d
   x16: 0x00000001967bda50  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000144d85300
   x20: 0x00000001978b7720  x21: 0x0000000000000008  x22: 0x0000000000000008  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x000000000004ffff  x26: 0x0000000144e161d0  x27: 0x000000016fd810e9
   x28: 0x0000000144d85300  fp: 0x000000016fd80ed0   lr: 0x0000000100659474
    sp: 0x000000016fd80ec0   pc: 0x0000000100659474 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Comment: Does your string contain fractional part? What region is set in "Language & Region" settings on device?

Comment: It does have fraction... The value came from a JSON, so i take the value out of the JSON object and it normally is a String, something like "2.34"  My language set is Portugues/Brasil. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `NSNumberFormatter` converts data according to current locale settings. In case of simulator it uses US locale and "." as decimal separator. In case of your device it uses "," as separator so it can't convert your data and `numberFromString` returns nil.

Try this:

```
extension String {
    func toDouble() -> Double? {
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
        return formatter.numberFromString(self)?.doubleValue
    }
}
```